# SQL: How to find all results older than 1 year

Tags: sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE YEAR(datecolumn) = YEAR(DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()))
```

From my understanding, this query will show everything in that table that is older than 1 year. I'm trying to get a list of items that were first stocked over a year ago. Is this the correct query to be running or could it be made easier?

I need the script to be able to run without a fixed date range. So say I run it today and it gives me 100 rows, if I run it tomorrow, because the script is looking at the date I run it, it might return a different result set.

Comment: This query can not use indexes

Comment: *Is this the correct query to be running* does it return the correct results? If so, yes.

Comment: _Is this the correct query_ Test it and validate the results. Simply replace the value of GETDATE() with some sample datetime values to know if the query is logically correct and returns the desired values. And really think about what "older than 1 year" really means. You seem to be using a sample set of data that does not contain more than two years of dates

Comment: Why are you using `year`? why not just `datecolumn <= dateadd(year,-1,getdate())`?  If you're after all records less than or equal to 1 year from current date.  It's the difference between 2021 and 2022  yes those are 1 year appart but in reality it's at 3 months now.. so not a "year"  So define what you mean by older than 1 year....

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I've put as much info in the original post as needed.

What I mean by 'older than 1 year' is anything from the date of running the script backwards.

Example:

I'm looking at a product I've been selling for a while. Due to me having around 900k different products I'm not sure when this product was first stocked. 
I want to run a set of SQL to show me all my products, on that date of running the query, that were first stocked from that date. I run the query on 26/02/2022. I want to see anything from 26/02/2021 and back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That query gives results for records of only the previous year.

To get records older than `(today - 1 year)` try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE datecolumn < DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

And to get records before the current year

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE datecolumn < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,1)
```

Comment: You want a LESS THAN comparison, not GREATER THAN

Comment: Oh right... "older"

Comment: Sorry for only getting round to this. Just tested the first script you made and it works perfectly! Done exactly what I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This will give you everything from last "year"

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE YEAR(datecolumn) < YEAR(GETDATE())
```

But you want it to change day by date.  In that case do this

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE datecolumn < DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: I've yet to run your queries but looking at the bottom one, that is what I am wanting. I'll respond back once I have tested! Thank you very much!